# Incorrect/outdated high/low temps in simpleweather.js

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this is obvious, but I just tinker and hack when it comes to coding anything.  I am trying to build a weather display page and have gotten everything the way I want it, but the high and low for the day seem to be stuck at the data for the day the page was created and have not updated in the two days since.  Is there something I am missing to get this data current?

Here is the js code:

```
if("geolocation" in navigator) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    loadWeather(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
});
} else {
loadweather("Danville, KY", "");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(getWeather, 60000);
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
$.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: 2389342,
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
        city = weather.city;
        temp = weather.temp+'&deg;';
        wcode = '<img class="weathericon" src="images/weathericons/' + weather.code + '.svg">';
        high = '<p>Today\'s High: '+weather.high+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</p>' ; 
        low = '<p>Today\'s Low: '+weather.low+'&deg; '+weather.units.temp+'</p>';

        $(".location").text(city);
        $(".temperature").html(temp);
        $(".climate_bg").html(wcode);
        $(".high").html(high);
        $(".low").html(low);

    },

    error: function(error) {
        $(".error").html('<p>' + error + '<p>');
    }
});
}
```

Comment: What's `getWeather`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot to me like you've forgotten to create the `getWeather` function. I think your first few lines of code  were meant to be inside it, so replacing everything prior to the `ready` call with this should solve it:

```
function getWeather() {
    if("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        loadWeather(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
    });
    } else {
    loadweather("Danville, KY", "");
    }
}
```

---

That said, your code as presented is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*: You want to declare the variables (`city`, `temp`, etc.) you're using in the ajax callback with `var`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried your suggested changes and it caused all the data to disappear on my page.  I did forget to mention that current temp and location were outputting correctly, I'm just getting outdated high/low info (from the day I wrote and published the code).  I'm open to more suggestions, but in the meantime I'll try to clean up my mess with the variables and again try the above code to see if there is a different result.